# Workflow of release by catkin_{generate_changelog, prepare_release}

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, releasing packages are getting easier and easier and even kind of fun. Thanks for the hard work guys!

I'm a bit confused with the steps of first-time release of a package (that I follow [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease)). There the steps go as:

---

```
$ cd %HOME_PKG_TOBE_RELEASED%
$ catkin_generate_changelog
```

Here `CHANGELOG.rst` files are generated in each package. I modify these files to replace the lines that have `Forthcoming` with the appropriate version number (and date if I wish). Then,

```
$ catkin_prepare_release
```

which bumps version of all packages inside the directory. Problem occurs next; the command complains that there aren't `changelog` entry corresponding to the new version.

---

Here I end up manually creating `tag` and push to the `upstream` repository, and move to the next steps in the tutorial.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it worth opening an enhancement request?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101066/workflow-of-release-by-catkin_%7Bgenerate_changelog,-prepare_release%7D/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Here CHANGELOG.rst files are generated in each package. I modify these files to replace the lines that have Forthcoming with the appropriate version number (and date if I wish).

`catkin_tag_changelog` does that for you and now `catkin_prepare_release` does that for you automatically.

The workflow should be:

```
$ catkin_generate_changelog
<edit changelog entries, do not touch forthcoming heading>
<commit changes to changelogs>
$ catkin_prepare_release
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2